# Image segmentation with watershed: over segmentation and merging connected regions

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to segment a 3D tomogram using the watershed algorithm.

Here my code (`a` is the tomogram I want to segment):

```
D = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(a)

localMax = feature.peak_local_max(D, indices=False, min_distance=30,
                                  labels=a,threshold_abs=6,exclude_border=1)
localMax2 = feature.peak_local_max(D, indices=True, min_distance=30,
                                   labels=a,threshold_abs=6,exclude_border=1)

markers = ndimage.label(localMax, structure=np.ones((3,3,3)))[0]
labels = morphology.watershed(-D,markers,mask=a)
```

The problem is that the algorithm over segments the regions, see picture (on the left side the raw tomogram, middle Euclidean distance map with seeds points (red dots), right the segmented image). If I use fewer seed points I do not get all the regions. Is there a way to merge adjacent regions?

[image: Images]

Comment: Did you try smoothing the input image before thresholding to reduce the complexity of the outlines? That will reduce the number of local maxima where you don't want them.

Comment: yes, i applied a closing for the image but there is a segmentation even in large regions as you can see on the picture

Comment: Apply a Gaussian filter *before* thresholding. The larger the filter, the simpler the outlines will be, and the fewer segments you'll get.